# Perl modules Scope::Upper Sub::Uplevel, what other modules are in use with modern perl?

Tags: perl, callstack

Trying to ged rid of Sub::Filter from in-house OOP. The code I am fixing is itself evaluated and my newly created wrapper should report proper sub name, but I have just  _ _ ANON _ _

```
$code_after = _stringify(qq{
     BEGIN {
         my \$orig = \\&$subname;
         my \$orig_attr = attributes::get(\\&$subname);
         no warnings 'redefine';
         my \$s = sub {\&Sub::Uplevel::uplevel(2, \$orig, \@_);};
         *$subname = sub {
             \@_ = \&\$s;
             return unless defined wantarray;
             ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's the question?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. It is:
Are there some modules like Scope::Upper and Sub::Uplevel to operate with call stack?
But Sub::Uplevel + Sub::Name solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Sub::Name`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Name) to redefine your anonymous sub name.

```
 use Sub::Name;
 *$subname = subname Whatever::Module::your_sub_name => sub {
```